Creating standard library modules with Premake
I am trying to create a premake script that creates a VS2022 project file that automatically creates C++23 standard library modules, i.e. where the option "Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules" is set.
I wanted to use vsprops for this. But no matter where I put the line
vsprops {BuildStlModules = "true"}

in the script, I always get the error “attempt to call a nil value (global ‘vsprops’)”. (Premake version 5.0beta2)
I've also tried
BuildStlModules = "On"

with the newest Version from Github. It does not generate an error, but has no effect either.
I would be grateful for any advice on what I am doing wrong.

Standard library != STL

From Preamke's doc, it is clear that it is available since Premake 5.0-beta3

I've found the solution. You have to use the latest version from Github (5.0 beta2 does not work). But the syntax is different from the one I tried above. With the line
buildstlmodules "On"

it works.
